# Client - Server or web services?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

This might seem like a strange question, however it suddenly hit me that i might be doing this wrong...

So, I've been working on an application for a while, and recently we switched from open source solutions to Microsoft solutions for the backend (OS, Database, Webserver).

Now, previously I've been using standard java web services for pulling and pushing data into our DB, however the vast majority of that has now been replaced with application roles and direct DB access from our clients (This is internal, no less of a security concern)

We still have a single application that i had planned to continue the use of web services with, this simply works as a single login, patching and launch platform for our other software, a basic portal. However reading up on .net services, web api and WCF I'm suddenly struck by the sensation that perhaps web services are in fact not the way to go here.

So basically, the services perform the following functions

1. Taking a username/password for the client, and confirming successful
   login.
2. Retrieving the version information for a list of installed
   applications.
3. Changing the users password Resetting the password in the event it
   was forgotten.

Now, are web services really the "best" (or more, simply a reasonable) way of providing this functionality, or would a more standard client server setup be a more reasonable way of achieving this, or perhaps i'm simply over thinking the case?

Comment: The question you're asking doesn't really have anything to do with the requirements you've provided.  This functionality can be achieved with clients directly accessing a database server, or by accessing some other service operations which internally directly access a database server.  The "best" approach is entirely subjective and depends on what other factors might be considered here.  If there are no other factors, the simplest approach is generally best (whatever you and your team think is simplest).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I think this is a classic case of my over thinking this. The answer by muhwu catches my line of thinking while reading into WCF, pretty much a case of this is so simple and the examples are generally much heavier and more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really difficult to say what the best way for your case is and I think it's more subjective than anything else.

That being said, while using a WCF service might be an "overkill" for something so simple. Building a server-client setup from scratch definitely sounds like an overkill. The base WCF service does a lot of the hard lifting for you with a relatively low cost and almost 0 cost in development. Unless it's becoming a performance bottleneck, I don't see why you'd switch solutions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I think you are correct and its that simplicity of my problem combined with the far more complex abilities of WCF that had me second guessing.

Comment: Yeah, I think if you do everything yourself, you'll end up shooting yourself in the metaphorical leg more often than not; especially with internally used software where performance is not an issue. WCF services are incredibly easy to set up at a basic level, especially when there are no security concerns. :)